# XXXenv の初期化時のeval "$(XXXenv init-)"の意味

Tags: ruby, python, linux, bash, shellscript

pyenv, rbenv等の使い方として.bashrcなりでeval`"$(XXXenv init -)"`という初期化をする必要があるようですが、2点不明な点があります。

- evalで実行する意味  
  直接 `XXXenv init -`とするのではなく、evalを使うことにどういった意図があるのでしょうか？
- `-`の意味  
  何を意味しているのか。カレントシェルで実行する`.`みたいなものなのかなとは思っているのですが、情報が見つかりませんでした。

**追記**  
XXXenv init は標準出力に文字列を返してそれをevalで実行しているのですね。直接実行しないでevalを使わせる理由はなんでしょうか？実行権限をつける必要がないからとかですかね？

`-`はただのXXXenvへの引数でしかないことはわかりました。`-`ってどういった意味で使われることが多いのでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば、`pyenv` のソースコード(シェルスクリプト)を参照してみてはどうでしょうか。[pyenv/pyenv-init at master · yyuu/pyenv · GitHub](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/blob/master/libexec/pyenv-init)

Comment: 逆に直接実行した場合を考えてみると、分かりやすいかと思います。evalの引数として渡しているのは、（追記にある通り）直接実行すると、標準出力に文字列を返すプログラムですよね？-については、bashなどのマニャアルに載っています。https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_bash/man1/bash.1.html　特殊パラメータのあたり。

Comment: @Toris bashの特殊パラメータについては間違っていると思います。それは`$-`についての記述です。 http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247643/meaning-of-a-hyphen-as-a-special-parameter

Comment: @paruwo 正しいのは、こちらでしたね。　bash オプション「--」 ＞-- はオプションの終わりを示し、それ以降のオプション処理を行いません。 -- 以降の引き数は全て、ファイル名や引き数として扱われます。 引き数 - は -- と同じです。

Comment: @Toris 一応の確認ですが、それはbash自体のオプションであり、bash上でコマンドを実行するときのオプションではありません。

Comment: @nekketsuuu コマンドも「似たような」処理を実装しているということです。例えば、-が現れたら、そこでオプションの解析を終了して、それ以降は出力対象にするといったように。

Comment: @Toris それはどこかにドキュメントされているのでしょうか？ 少なくともbashのmanはbashのオプションについてしか言及していないように見えるのですが。。。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 「似たような」の部分は一般論にあたる部分です。一緒に、これを貼っておいた方がよかったかもしれませんね。http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch10s05.html　Command-Line Options　>When you're choosing command-line option letters for your program, look at the manual pages for similar tools. Try to use the same option letters they use for the analogous functions of your program. 　--(または-)については、解釈が様々あるようです。http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash?rq=1

Comment: pyenv initについては、-は、入出力のリダイレクトというよりも、インタラクティブモードを有効にするオプション（dosプロンプトなどで使う、echo on）の方が近いかと思います。

Comment: @Toris ご指摘にあった "The Art of Unix Programming" のページには、以下の記述があります。 `Many tools accept a bare hyphen, not associated with any option letter, as a pseudo-filename directing the application to read from standard input.` ( http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch10s05.html より引用)　翻訳すると「多くのツールが、どのオプション文字列もついていないただのハイフンを、アプリケーションに標準入力から読ませるための擬似ファイル名としている。」です。`-`の解釈がこれに定まっていないことは私の回答でも触れた通りです。ただし、Torisさんが引用なさっているUnix.SEの質問は`--`に関するものです。

Comment: @Toris [DOSのechoコマンド](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands#ECHO) はインタラクティブモードとは関係ないように思います。また、確かに`nslookup`コマンドでは`-`を使うことによってインタラクティブモード（対話モード）になります（[参考: man nslookup](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/bind/man8/nslookup.8.html)）。しかし `pyenv init -` は対話操作をしているわけではないので、インタラクティブモードに近くは無いと私は思います。

Comment: @Toris そろそろコメントが長くなってきましたので、何か気になる点がございましたら、ご自身で`-`について回答なさるか、この議論をチャットに移行するのが良いのではないかと思います。スタック・オーバーフローの特性上、多くの回答が集まることが望ましいのではないかと私は思いますので、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### evalについて

今回の場合、`eval`を使いたい理由の1つは、シェルの環境変数や関数を設定したいということにあると思います。変数でも関数でも状況は大体同じなので、以下では変数についてのみ説明します。

`eval`をつけずにinitスクリプトを実行するとわかりますが、`pyenv init`や`rbenv init`ではそれぞれの環境変数を設定するために`export`を使っています。
しかし、シェルにおいてシェルスクリプトはサブシェル等で実行されるため、コマンド内で変数を`export`しても元のシェルにはなんら影響がありません。

たとえば、bashにおいて変数`EXAMPLE`を1に設定したかったとします。このとき、`export`しているシェルスクリプトを直に実行しても意味がありません。

```
$ cat test1.sh
export EXAMPLE=1
$ ./test1.sh
$ echo $EXAMPLE

$
```

そこで`eval`を使うと、この処理は以下のように書けます。

```
$ cat test2.sh
echo 'export EXAMPLE=1'
$ eval "$(./test2.sh)"
$ echo $EXAMPLE
1
$
```

このような処理をするために、init系のスクリプトで`eval`を使うのではないかと思います。

尚、上の動作は、bashにおいて`.`コマンドないし`source`コマンドを使って`. test1.sh`と書いても良いですが、このコマンドは他のシェルと互換しないことがあります。具体的にはたとえばfishにおいては`.`がdeprecatedで`source`を使うことを推奨していますが([参考1](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#source)、[2](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/310))、特定のkshにおいては`source`がありません([参考](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58514/what-is-the-difference-between-and-source-in-shells))。

また、より一般の場合、`eval`を使いたい理由は他にもあります。["eval command in Bash and its typical uses"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses) などをご覧ください。

#### `-`について

シェルスクリプトにおいて、ハイフン1文字は「標準入力から読んで下さい」「標準出力に書いてください」といった意味になることが多いです。（そういう意味にしているコマンドが多いというだけであり、普通シェル側が特別に処理する記号になっていないというだけなので、例外はあります。たとえばbashの`cd`ビルトインコマンドでは`cd -`は「1つ前のディレクトリに移る」になります）

`pyenv init`においても、[ソースコード](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/blob/master/libexec/pyenv-init)を見る限り、そのように処理しているようです。`rbenv init`も[同様です](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/master/libexec/rbenv-init)。

参考

- ["What does dash “-” at the end of a command mean?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41828/what-does-dash-at-the-end-of-a-command-mean)
- ["Usage of dash (-) in place of a filename"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename)

  - "shell script single hyphen" (またはdash) などで検索すると出てきます。

Comment: dashは、パイプで前段の出力を受ける場合などによく使うので、この説明もあるとよいかも。　>The "-" can be used to pipe stdout to other commands.  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#DASHREF2　Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide　Chapter 3. Special Characters